# Is there a analog of complete.cases for variables in R?

Tags: r

Here is an example for illustration:

```
x = data.frame(x1=1:3, x2=2:4, x3=3:5)
x
#   x1 x2 x3
# 1  1  2  3
# 2  2  3  4
# 3  3  4  5
x[2, 1] = NA
x[3, 2] = NA
complete.cases(x)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
x[complete.cases(x), , drop=FALSE]
#   x1 x2 x3
# 1  1  2  3
```

What if instead complete cases, I want to filter for complete variables (columns)? In the example above it should be something like:

```
x[,3,drop=FALSE]
#   x3
# 1  3
# 2  4
# 3  5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or something like this:

```
 x[, complete.cases(t(x)), drop=FALSE] # Tks Simon
```

Comment: +1 the simple ones are the best ones. I'd wrap with a `x[]` to return what the OP wants, i.e. `x[complete.cases(t(x))]`

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this :

```
R> x[,sapply(x, function(v) sum(is.na(v))==0), drop=FALSE]
  x3
1  3
2  4
3  5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply` to check the columns for missing values and subset using that result:

```
x[sapply(x,function(y) !any(is.na(y)))]
  x3
1  3
2  4
3  5
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a cleaner strategy here, but I think the following function will also work:

```
x = data.frame(x1=1:3, x2=2:4, x3=3:5)
x[2, 1] = NA
x[3, 2] = NA

complete.cols = function(dat){   
  non.missing.test = apply(dat,2,function(t){sum(is.na(t))==0})
  dat.complete.cols = data.frame(dat[,which(non.missing.test == TRUE)])
  names(dat.complete.cols) = names(dat)[which(non.missing.test == TRUE)]
  return(dat.complete.cols)
}

complete.cols(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This little function should work:

```
for (a in c(1:length(x))){
    ifelse(TRUE%in%is.na(x[,a]),print ('INCOMPLETE'),print ('COMPLETE'))
}
```